# Formatted tooltip in Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I want to add a formatted tooltip to one of my div but I can't get it right. this is what I have:

```
render() {
    var scope = this,
        getTooltip = function(product){
            return ('<div>' + 
                        '<div>Stock <div className="right floated">' + product.stock + '</div></div>' + 
                    '</div>');
        }
return (
       <span data-html={getTooltip(product)}>{product.Stock()}</span>
       )
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the jQuery to initiate the tooltip as your component is mounted?

```
componentDidMount() {
  $(yourSpanClassnameOrId)
     .popup({
       position : 'left',
       inline: true
     })
 }
```